# Create Triggers on SYSUSER table in sql Anywhere 16

Tags: triggers, sybase, sqlanywhere

I want to call a certain procedure that logs everytime a database user is created or deleted in the db ( sql Anywhere 16).
For this i have written a Function that should be called via a trigger when a row is inserted or deleted from table SYS.SYSUSER.

However, I am not able to create a trigger on this table.
Am i allowed to create trigger on this or is there someother way to get notified whenever a user is created or deleted for db?

New to sybase please help.

heres is my create trigger code

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER INSERT ON sys.sysuser
REFERENCING NEW AS newRecord
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
      -- 
END;
```

Comment: `sysuser` is a view.  The underlying table is `sys.isysuser`  That may be why you can't create the trigger, but i don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a trigger on a system table. You can create a handler for "system events", which are described in the online [SQL Anywhere documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbadmin/event-types.html). Unfortunately, creation or deletion of users is not a system event that can be handled. I don't believe there's a way short of polling that you can do what you want to do.

*Full disclosure: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: I am sorry , but I want to know what do you mean by polling??

Comment: Polling = checking occasionally. You could create your own table that contains all of the current users, then every now and again check the system table to see if any new users have been created or existing users deleted.

Comment: That is how I was currently working on , but thought someone would know a better solution, what about through transaction logs?

Comment: Yes, you could get that information through the transaction log as well. You could use `dbtran` to translate the log and then look through the output for "create user/grant connect" and "drop user/revoke connect".